# Safe List to Textfile and read it with json

Tags: c#, json, uwp

I am trying to display an list in an listview in Visual Studio that was first serialized and then deserialized. Everything works fine but my problem is that the list is displayed in an very weird format you can see it in the picture below.

Heres my code so far:

```
        private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        KalenderClass k1 = new KalenderClass();
        k1.termin = TerminTextbox.Text;
        k1.datum = DatePicker1.Date;
        k1.person = PersonTextbox.Text;
        kList.Add(k1);
        SaveData(kList);
        
    }

    private async void SaveData(List<KalenderClass> kList)
    {
        StorageFolder ordner = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        StorageFile datei = await ordner.CreateFileAsync("Kalender.txt", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(datei, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(kList));
        showDialog("Daten wurden in Datei geschrieben");


    }

    private async void ReadButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StorageFolder ordner = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        string path = ordner.Path;
        StorageFile datei = await ordner.GetFileAsync("Kalender.txt");
        string inhalt = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(datei);
        var k = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(inhalt);
        TerminListview.Items.Add(k);
    }
```

I dont want to add the whole List k to the listview but just the new object.
And here is the way it is displayed:
[image: Screenshot]

I want it to be a format, for example:
Termin 1:
Date:
Person:

I hope you guys can help me

Comment: try to remove before add : `TerminListview.Clear()`

Comment: thank you! is there an option to remove the items through clicks?

Answer (score 0):

**Change CreationCollisionOption from:**

`CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists`

**To:**

`CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting`

**Or you can refresh the list inside the SaveButton_Click method as the following:**

```
private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    kList = new List<KalenderClass>(); // <== This line will reset the list
    KalenderClass k1 = new KalenderClass();
    k1.termin = TerminTextbox.Text;
    k1.datum = DatePicker1.Date;
    k1.person = PersonTextbox.Text;
    kList.Add(k1);
    SaveData(kList);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your edit helped me out. Do you know if there is an way to display the list in another way or even in an format?

Comment: @Chrizzy, If you mean displaying it to the users, yes there are many ways to display any data or list, but it depends on what the purpose of the program, and what users expect from your application.
On the other hand, it is very useful to learn how to manipulate data in c# with LINQ, which is probably one of the most important things you want to learn in C#.

Comment: Do you any link or tutorial for that?

Comment: You can start with this one, it is a good tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yClSNQdVD7g ,